# MySQL/PHP Update statement outputting white page with no errors

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to update records in my table with the followin, my problem is however that my browser outputs an empty white page with no source, Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php

require 'dbconfig.php';

//Always place this code at the top of the Page
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    // Redirection to login page twitter or facebook
    header("location: index.php");
}



function safe($value){
   return mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}

// Variables
$_SESSION['username'];
$_SESSION['oauth_provider'];
$uid = $_SESSION['id'];
$email = safe($_POST["email"]);
$credits = safe($_POST["credits"]);



 $query = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET email= '$email' WHERE id='$uid'") or die(mysql_error());


?>
```

Comment: Well I see you arent outputting anything, so that is most likely the problem.

Comment: Shouldnt we avoid using mysql_query though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have assigned a variable to your query, but you are not running it.

```
 $query = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET email= '$email' WHERE id='$uid'") or die(mysql_error());
```

So, the above is just a redundant code. to run it, you should call `$query`, like this

```
if($query){
echo 'Updated performed';
}else{
echo 'Update failed';
}
```

**Note** I'm not encouraging you to use `mysql_` functions as they are weak, vulnerable and deprecated. Intead you should learn more about [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Comment: the query is run, but the result is not used. Thats two pairs of shoes.

Comment: Ahh sorry, completely missed it, works great, thanks @php NoOb

Answer (score 1):

You are not displaying anything after DB operation. So nothing will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET email= '$email' WHERE id='$uid'") or die(mysql_error());

$sql_query = mysql_query($query);

if(mysql_affected_rows()) {
    $msg = "something has changed!";
} else {
    $msg = "nothing has changed!";
}
```